# How to create a listbox similar to that in People Hub in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: xaml, user-interface, listbox, windows-phone-7.1

How do I design a listbox in Windows phone 7 similar to the one in People hub. Something like how the alphabet headers move in the contacts list.
Something like how the alphabet headers move in the contacts list.

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/213/contactsg.jpg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the LongListSelector in the Silverlight Toolkit.

[Here's a link to the Silverlight Toolkit for Mango](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/75888)

and here's a good example of using the toolkit. [Long List Selector in Depth](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)

Comment: @JeswinSimon with no XAML at all, sure. Although it's probably easier with it. That link is more getting to know the framework.

Comment: @JeswinSimon download the source & sample for the Silverlight toolkit, and you'll see a easy example. If you are trying to create it without any XAML at all, it will be no different then how you'd create a Grid / etc. completely in code.